# How to set Date to 1/1/0001 using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I write new Date(1, 0, 1), but get 1/1/1901.

While new Date(1001,0,1) get 1/1/1001 as expected.

How to set date when the year is before 1000 A.D.

Comment: MomentJS is your answer https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Good dupetarget find @Raja.

Comment: Just FYI, I've deleted my answer and posted it on the dupetarget instead. BTW: TIL that JavaScript applies special handling to year values 0-99, I didn't know that. Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a `Date` using the year, month, day (and optional time parameters) constructor with year in the range 0–99, because those years map to 1900–1999 (see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)). However you can construct a `Date` object using a string:

```
new Date('0001-01-01')
```

Since this only applies to the years 0–99, you can construct later years before 1000 AD fine:

```
new Date(900, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Probably moot, but "0001-01-01" will be treated as UTC, whereas `new Date(1,0,1)` will be treated as local. :-)